# export was not found error - after updating to angular-10

Tags: javascript, angular, web, angular10

After updating my project to angular-10 i'm getting an error:

```
ERROR in ./src/someDir/someService.service.ts 17:33-14
"export 'format' was not found in 'some-library'
```

when going to 'some-library' there form function is exported

```
export function format(options?: LBSOptions): any;
```

any idea what could go wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Just change your target in tsconfig.json to ES6 or above.
I had the same problem and it helps me to fix it.